# How can I reduce a bezier curve using a slider till all points converge to it's original midpoint

Tags: unity

I am using the code from the question [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/159583/adding-functionality-to-make-individual-anchor-points-of-bezier-continuous-or-no) to create bezier curves (I didn't think it was necessary to repost the code here since I haven't made any significant changes to it yet).

I have a symmetric bezier curve (please see image) that I want to reduce till all points converge at the midpoint of the original curve. I would like to preserve it's symmetry while it moves. 
I would like achieve this using a  `float` slider (with values from 0 to 1) in editor mode.

[image]

Comment: Your image suggests you're just rescaling it, but I could also interpret it as you wanting the reduction to follow along the path of the curve as well. Difference is that the line never moves, only how much of it is visible. Which are you looking for? And do you need a new curve for other reasons, or just need less of the curve to be visible?

Comment: @ChrisMills-Price I am interested in the latter, the reduction following along the curve path. The original curve is symmetric, so I need it to reduce symmetrically till it reaches the midpoint. I need a new symmetric curve to be formed for each slider value from zero to one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a cubic Bezier curve type with control points `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and methods to evaluate, given a parameter `0 <= t <= 1`, both:

- a position on the curve at `t`

  ie.  \$\vec p = (1-t)^3 \vec a + 3 t (1-t)^2 \vec b + 3 t^2(1-t) \vec c + t^3 \vec d\$
- the first derivative of that position with respect to the parameter `t`

  ie.   \$\frac {\delta \vec p} {\delta t} = 3 (1-t)^2 (\vec b - \vec a) + 6 t (1-t) (\vec c - \vec b) + 3 t^2 (\vec d - \vec c)\$

Then we can choose new control points for an arbitrary interval `start <= t <= end` on this curve like so:

```
static CubicBezier IntervalFromTo(CubicBezier curve, float start, float end) {

    float scale = (end - start)/3f;

    var a = curve.PositionAt(start);

    var b = a + curve.DerivativeAt(start) * scale;

    var d = curve.PositionAt(end);

    var c = d - curve.DerivativeAt(end) * scale;

    return new CubicBezier(a, b, c, d);
}
```

If you have a `size` parameter that runs between `0` (just the midpoint) and `1` (the whole original curve), then you can compute your symmetrical subset as a special case:

```
subsetCurve = IntervalFromTo(originalCurve, 0.5f - 0.5f * size, 0.5f + 0.5f * size);
```

I recommend that you keep your `originalCurve` unchanged throughout this manipulation, and make a fresh `subsetCurve` from the original each time something changes, rather than overwriting your original with each change. Keeping this separation will ensure you don't get unwanted vibrations or degradation due to accumulating rounding errors.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the original question, but is this what they want, or just a simple rendering of t going from, 0% to 100%, then 10% to 90%, then 20% to 80%, etc. until it's just the point at t=0.5?

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier, haven’t been here for a few days. I’m using the code in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/159583/adding-functionality-to-make-individual-anchor-points-of-bezier-continuous-or-no, the only difference is I added a `LineRenderer` to `PathCreator` for the `path`.  I am not sure how I’ll get the `subPath` to display the line since the the original curve’s line is linked to the `pathCreator` and all other `path` functionality is linked to the original `path` in the editor. Please see the related parts of the editor class in https://pastebin.com/9zkLtMBP.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Using the code you provided, the bezier curve points converge to a midpoint different from the original curve hence the shape isn't maintained as this happens. The curve flattens into a straight line. I wanted the curve shape to be maintained as the points converge (with the two end points moving along the curve) to the midpoint of the original curve. Also, this process is irreversible. Any attempt to change the `size`  value back to 1.0 still leaves the all points at a midpoint.

Comment: I'm afraid you have not implemented the method correctly if you're observing a change in the shape of the curve. I'll upload a gif shortly demonstrating that this method preserves the curve's shape when implemented as described.

Comment: Okay. I'll also take another look at my implementation. But I would be glad if you could also take a look at it. My implementation of `IntervalFromTo` is http://pastebin.com/9zkLtMBP by the same name.

Comment: I don't see where you use the values you've computed in your local variables a,b,c,d to create a new curve

Comment: `subPath = PathIntervalFromTo(path, 0.5f - 0.5f * curveLengthValue, 0.5f + 0.5f * curveLengthValue, 0);` in `OnInspectorGUI()`

Comment: Pardon me, I used `curve[0]`, `curve[1]`, `curve[2]` and `curve[3]` instead of a, b, c, d in `IntervalFromTo` since they represent the control points of my `Path curve`. Could there be an issue with this?

Comment: @DMGregory I'm still trying to figure this out :)

Comment: @DMGregory I realised that I needed new variables as you stated for `a` to `d`. I tested `originalCurve = IntervalFromTo(originalCurve, 0.5f - 0.5f * size, 0.5f + 0.5f * size);` though I'm suppose to use use a new `subsetCurve` just to have an idea of if it will move along the curve, and it did. My issue, seems to be how to introduce a `subsetCurve` in the editor that will respond  to the functionality such as symmetry and all other stuff that the originalCurve had.

Comment: @DMGregory Wow, this is incredible. This is partly what I've been looking for. I need to achieve this for a bezier curve of order n and also for points all points converging to one end instead of the middle. I've been trying to achieve this for months. Would you recommend I ask a new question or can this answer can be updated to cover what I mentioned since they're related?

Comment: Ask a new question, @Hilarious404. You can link to this one for context.

Comment: @DMGregory just added the question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/164115/how-to-converge-all-points-of-a-bezier-curve-of-order-n-to-one-end-and-also-the

Comment: @DMGregory from my original question above, how can I converge all points to one end of the curve instead of the middle?

Comment: Use the same formulas, keeping `end = 1` and blending `start` from 0 toward 1.

Comment: @DMGregory I tried extended this for a multi-segment cubic curve but it briskly moves through the first few curves (faster than it should) and moves normally through the last curve. The code that I used is here https://pastebin.com/hjxZv4QP

Comment: Then that's a different problem you should ask about in a new question, @Zizo.

Comment: @DMGregory Okay, I just asked a new question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/168172/how-to-move-points-of-a-multi-segmented-bezier-curve-to-one-side