# When using Prefab Mode only one game object is adjusted while the others need to be manually selected in hierarchy window for changes

Tags: unity

I created a bezier curve prefab using the code in the post [How to create an illustrator/photoshop-like pentool for creating bezier curves in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/164911/how-to-create-an-illustrator-photoshop-like-pentool-for-creating-bezier-curves-i). I added a few copies of the prefab to my scene. When I open the original prefab in prefab mode (I am using Unity 2019.1.0a8) and adjust any of the points it only affects one of the prefabs, the changes are not recognised in the scene view till I select the other objects manually.

I added `SceneView.RepaintAll();` after calling `path.MovePoint(i, newPos);` in the `Draw()` method but it still doesn't update the others.

Could it be that I haven't serialised by variables correctly? 
How can I get all of the objects created from the prefab to recognise changes immediately when the original prefab is altered?

Comment: Where the instances in your scene parented to (or parents of) other prefabs in the scene?  This seems to break automatic updating.

Comment: @JeffUK no the instances are not parents or children of other prefabs